# Solving twice the differential of a function with double integrand

Tags: calculus

Find $F''(\pi)$ if 
$$
F(x) = \int_x^{\sin x}\left(
\int_0^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du
\right) dt.
$$

How do you solve this equation using the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Using the FTC, more info please!

Comment: I have tried splitting the integral to two with sinx and x as both the upper bounds. After differentiating the outer integral, I obtained two terms. First term with a product of cosx and the inner integral, the second term with the inner integral alone. After another round of differentiation, I obtained 3 terms, of which I could not find the solution of the product of sinx and the inner integral.

Answer (score 0):

By [Leibniz rule](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule),

$$F'(x) = \int_x^{\sin x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(
\int_0^{\sin t}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du
\right) dt+\int_0^{\sin \sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du\cos x\\-\int_0^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du\\=\left(\int_0^{\sin \sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du\right)\cos x -\int_0^{\sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du.$$

Similarly

$$F''(x) =\left(\sqrt{1+(\sin \sin x)^4} (\sin \sin x)'\right) \cos x+\left(\int_0^{\sin \sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du\right) (-\sin x) \\-\sqrt{1+(\sin x)^4} \cos x\\=\left(\sqrt{1+(\sin \sin x)^4} (\cos \sin x\cos x)\right) \cos x+\left(\int_0^{\sin \sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du\right) (-\sin x) \\-\sqrt{1+(\sin x)^4} \cos x.$$

Hence, $F''(\pi)=1+0-(-1)=2$

---

Actually, in this special case, you don't need to use generalized Leibniz rule. Since the integrand is independent of $x$. For example, you can view $\int_0^{\sin \sin x}\sqrt{1+u^4} \ du$ as $g\circ h(x),$ where $g(y)=\int_0^{y} \sqrt{1+u^4} \ du,h(x)=\sin \sin x$., then by FTC and chain rule, $$g\circ h(x)'=g'(h(x))h'(x)\\=\sqrt{1+(\sin \sin x)^4}(\sin \sin x)'$$

Hence you can get similar result.

Comment: The question asked the student to use the FTC. Clearly since the $\sin(\pi)=0$ then the result is $0$.

Comment: @Alvin I have added a similar method using FTC and chain rule. I hope it can help you.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the enlightenment. ^^

Comment: Hi John, I have tried working out the solution, but I don't get 1-1 in the end. The last term should be +1 instead of -1, am I correct? Therefore the answer should be 1+1=2.

Comment: @Alvin Sorry, you are right. I will edit my answer.